# How to add a newer version of Hibernate in JBoss AS 7.1.3

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, jboss

I have an installation of JBoss AS 7.1.3 (not a chance to change that) that comes with Hibernate 4.1.6. Due to a bug in such a version (no workarounds available) I have to update my application to use Hibernate 5.1.

Since this happens in a particular application, only that one has to receive the newer version of Hibernate, other applications in the same server must continue to use the already present Hibernate version.

How to:

1. Add a new Hibernate version to an existing JBoss AS 7.1 installation?
2. Configure my Eclipse Maven project to use that Hibernate version?

TIA!

## Update1

This is my current `module.xml` file, located at `...\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\modules\org\hibernate\5.1.10.Final`:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hibernate:5.1.10.Final">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-core-5.1.10.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.10.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-infinispan-5.1.10.Final.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="asm.asm"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        <module name="org.infinispan" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.javassist"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate" slot="4" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.envers" services="import" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control class loading in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. It should look something like this (please read the docs of your jboss version about the exact configuration parameters):

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="5.1.10.Final" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

You may also need to add the following property in the `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.1.10.Final"/>
```

Also, create a new module and copy the necessary jars for the Hibernate version you want to use; [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7) are more details about class loading in AS7.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your instructions seem to be in the right path. I had read all those documents, but could not gather some little details together to make it all work. At this point it seems JBoss is indeed trying to provide my application with 5.1.10.Final version of Hibernate, but during the server startup I get this error: `ParseError at [row,col]:[26,72]
Message: Invalid/mismatched module name (expected org.hibernate:5.1.10.Final)`. The message would be obvious if my module.xml didn't have `name="org.hibernate:5.1.10.Final"`. Any clues?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know by heart what could be the cause for that, I suggest you ask a separate question for that in which you provide all the details, as it seems related to the configuration format in the jboss version you use.

Comment: Your answer is correct and you deserve the bounty prize! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the existing jars by the new jars  (under modules/org/hibernate) and make sure you have the right dependancies.
Once the jars are replaced, you need to make sure that your jars names are updated. So edit module.xml by updating resource-root paths which should match the new modules.

In your pom.xml, make sure ou update the modules versions which should match the versions you specified under your jboss installation.

Comment: As I said, replacing is not an option, since I have to support two different versions of Hibernate